# Can someone explain this Pandas groupby() behaviour?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm doing an introductory course to pandas on coursera. The first line of the code is a small part of a dataframe containing weather data ( maximum and minimum temperatures, marked TMAX and TMIN respectively ).  I dont understand why groupby() does the following:

```
df = pd.read_json('{"Data_Value":{"10073":3.3,"10079":-4.4,"17153":15.0,"17155":-1.1,"18049":5.6,"18066":-3.9,"18232":-1.7,"18261":5.6,"1860":15.0,"1906":-1.7,"19769":-3.3,"19772":12.8,"2035":-1.7,"2073":14.4,"24805":-5.6,"24863":4.4,"2812":-5.0,"3058":12.8,"31715":15.6,"31718":-4.4,"32266":15.0,"32274":-5.0,"35479":-3.9,"35771":12.2,"35785":-3.9,"39454":2.8,"39468":-2.8,"39565":-2.2,"39569":14.4,"41309":-3.9,"41334":3.3,"49030":15.0,"49074":-3.9,"49823":15.0,"49827":-3.9,"55067":-2.8,"55102":6.7,"55424":15.0,"55428":-4.4,"60994":13.3,"60995":0.0},"Date":{"10073":1104537600000,"10079":1104537600000,"17153":1104537600000,"17155":1104537600000,"18049":1104537600000,"18066":1104537600000,"18232":1104537600000,"18261":1104537600000,"1860":1104537600000,"1906":1104537600000,"19769":1104537600000,"19772":1104537600000,"2035":1104537600000,"2073":1104537600000,"24805":1104537600000,"24863":1104537600000,"2812":1104537600000,"3058":1104537600000,"31715":1104537600000,"31718":1104537600000,"32266":1104537600000,"32274":1104537600000,"35479":1104537600000,"35771":1104537600000,"35785":1104537600000,"39454":1104537600000,"39468":1104537600000,"39565":1104537600000,"39569":1104537600000,"41309":1104537600000,"41334":1104537600000,"49030":1104537600000,"49074":1104537600000,"49823":1104537600000,"49827":1104537600000,"55067":1104537600000,"55102":1104537600000,"55424":1104537600000,"55428":1104537600000,"60994":1104537600000,"60995":1104537600000},"Element":{"10073":"TMAX","10079":"TMIN","17153":"TMAX","17155":"TMIN","18049":"TMAX","18066":"TMIN","18232":"TMIN","18261":"TMAX","1860":"TMAX","1906":"TMIN","19769":"TMIN","19772":"TMAX","2035":"TMIN","2073":"TMAX","24805":"TMIN","24863":"TMAX","2812":"TMIN","3058":"TMAX","31715":"TMAX","31718":"TMIN","32266":"TMAX","32274":"TMIN","35479":"TMIN","35771":"TMAX","35785":"TMIN","39454":"TMAX","39468":"TMIN","39565":"TMIN","39569":"TMAX","41309":"TMIN","41334":"TMAX","49030":"TMAX","49074":"TMIN","49823":"TMAX","49827":"TMIN","55067":"TMIN","55102":"TMAX","55424":"TMAX","55428":"TMIN","60994":"TMAX","60995":"TMIN"},"ID":{"10073":"USW00014833","10079":"USW00014833","17153":"USC00207320","17155":"USC00207320","18049":"USW00014853","18066":"USW00014853","18232":"USC00205050","18261":"USC00205050","1860":"USC00202308","1906":"USC00205822","19769":"USC00205450","19772":"USC00205450","2035":"USC00202308","2073":"USC00203712","24805":"USW00094889","24863":"USW00094889","2812":"USC00203712","3058":"USC00205822","31715":"USC00205451","31718":"USC00205451","32266":"USC00208202","32274":"USC00208202","35479":"USC00201502","35771":"USC00200230","35785":"USC00200230","39454":"USC00205563","39468":"USC00205563","39565":"USC00200842","39569":"USC00200842","41309":"USC00208080","41334":"USC00208080","49030":"USC00207312","49074":"USC00207312","49823":"USC00200228","49827":"USC00200228","55067":"USC00200032","55102":"USC00200032","55424":"USC00207308","55428":"USC00207308","60994":"USW00004848","60995":"USW00004848"}}')
dfmax1 = df.groupby(["Date"]).max()
print(dfmax1)
```

results in :

```
 Data_Value Element           ID
Date                                       
2005-01-01        15.6    TMIN  USW00094889
```

Looking for the maximum temperature returns an element marked as "TMIN" .This element isnt present in the original dataframe, but the value of the maximum temperature is correct.

Using a mask for only "TMAX" values fixes the issue:

```
dfmax2 = (df[df['Element']=='TMAX']).groupby(["Date"]).max()
```

Also, attempting to get the minimum temperature with the min() function returns a an element that is marked as TMAX . Can anyone explain why this happens?

Comment: Please chose a more expressive title.

Answer (score 0):

The first detail worth to mention is that *read_json* attempts by default
to convert **datelike** columns to *datetime* type and one of cases when
a column is treated as *datelike* is that its name is *date* (apparently,
case insensitive).

You can confirm it running *df.info()* and checking that it contains:

```
Date  ...  datetime64[ns]
```

Note also that every row has the same *Date* (*2005-01-01*), so *df.groupby*
groups all rows into a **single** group.

Another detail is that in this case *max* function is applied to **each column**
in each group and returns the max value in each column.

Because you have a single group, you can check it, running:

```
df.Data_Value.max()
df.Element.max()
df.ID.max()
```

as separate commands and you will get just **the same values**.
Note also that *TMIN* is lexicographically the last value from *Element* column,
so it is the max value from this column.

I also disagree that *"TMIN"* is not present in the DataFrame.
Print *df* (it contains only 41 rows) and you will see that *Element* column
has only *'TMIN'* and *'TMAX'* values.

And to get full row for each *Date* with index and max temperature,
you can run:

```
df.reset_index().groupby(["Date"])\
    .apply(lambda grp: grp.loc[grp.Data_Value.idxmax()])\
    .set_index('index', drop=True)
```

The result is:

```
18     Data_Value       Date Element           ID
index                                            
31715        15.6 2005-01-01    TMAX  USC00205451
```

Caution: The initial *"18"* is the (new) index of the max row found,
printed only if grouping contains a single group.
Otherwise (if there are more groups) it doesn't appear.